# Why am I seeing "Promise { <pending> }" from this code on repl.it?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I know this question has been asked a lot on stackoverflow and I've searched a lot and still am not able to understand.

```js
async function testFunc() {
  var test = await getSomething();
  //test.resolve();
  console.log("hello" + test);
  return "";
}
testFunc().then(token => {}).catch(x => {});

function getSomething() {
    return "ex";
}
```

In most answers it is suggested to use .then() to resolve the promise, but I've done that and I still get promise pending. What is wrong in this ?

Tested this on https://repl.it/repls/UntrueLankySorting

It shows me this:

```
helloex
=> Promise { <pending> }
```

Comment: Side note: *"...it is suggested to use .then() to resolve the promise..."* `then` doesn't resolve the promise. It *observes* the settlement of the promise.

Comment: Side note 2: There's no reason to `await getSomething()` as  `getSomething` doesn't return a promise.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thats right, in this example await is not required. I tried it on https://repl.it/repls/UntrueLankySorting (online NodeJS) and got the output as Promise pending

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Tested this on https://repl.it/repls/UntrueLankySorting

It's showing you the result of the call to `catch` here:

> ```
> testFunc().then(token => {}).catch(x => {});
> ```

You don't care about that promise, it's just that that environment shows it to you. It is indeed a pending promise as of when `catch` returns, but it gets settled later.

That's just an aspect of the environment you were running it in. The code itself is fine other than the issue I mentioned in comments (that `getSomething` doesn't return a promise, so there's no need to `await` it).

In a comment you've asked:

> Would `catch` return in this case? Since no error is thrown it should resolve at `then` right?

`then` and `catch` always return a promise. The promise they return gets resolved or rejected depending on what happens to the promise you called `then`/`catch` on and, if their handler gets run, what happens in the handler and what it returns.

In this example, here's what that code does:

1. Calls `testFunc` and gets the promise it returns (`async` functions always return promises). Call that Promise A.
2. Calls `then` on Promise A. `then` returns a new promise (Promise B).
3. Calls `catch` on Promise B. `catch` returns a new promise (Promise C).
4. `repl.it` shows you Promise C, which is pending at that point.¹
5. Promise A fulfills², which calls the `then` handler. The `then` handler (effectively) returns `undefined`.
6. That fulfills Promise B with the value `undefined`, which fulfills Promise C (without calling the `catch` handler, because the promise was fulfilled, not rejected).

---

¹ It would be permissible for an implementation to show a fulfilled state there instead *in this example*, but for all intents and purposes, it's best to think of the promise as pending at that point. Since code can never directly observe the state of a promise, your code can't tell the difference.

² Similarly, it would be permissible if it were already fulfilled before `then` was called on it, but similarly you can never see that directly in code, so...

Comment: Would catch return in this case? Since no error is thrown it should resolve at then right?

Comment: @user1692342 - `then` and `catch` always return a promise. I've added some detail to the answer to help clarify.